# Form data is not going into parse table on save

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, parse-platform

I made a simple form to get username and to save it into my **parse.com** table on server. I get the value from the username field and call save on my parse object in **validateForm** function. Below is my code snippet.

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        User name:<br><input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Below is my script code.

```
function validateForm()
{
        Parse.initialize("w3RDajuAiDvrYCcM2DqmmD0PCuSrZKZGxp6y1n5g", "BDlDaVUik94zlmHEwWZr3WRzSwQ3JlPUXUBLNhU2");

    var username = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;

    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
    var gameScore = new GameScore();    
    gameScore.set("username", username);

gameScore.save(null, {
    success: function(gameScore) {
    alert('New object created with objectId: ' + gameScore.id);
    },
    error: function(gameScore, error) {
    alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
    }
});  }
```

I am getting this error>>> **Failed to create new object, with error code
                           XMLHttpRequest failed{"statusText";",status":
                           0,"responseURL":",response";"...........**

But insertion works fine when I do not use a function call and hard code the value in script. Please help. I just to save the user input in my table on submit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using 
    event.preventDefault();
at the first line inside your validateForm() function before Parse.initialize(). With that, you need to explicitly do form submit inside the success block though.  Parse requests are asynchronous. Your validation function may finish running faster than the Parse request gets processed, that is a chance, assuming rest of your functionality is implemented alright. Hope that helped.

Comment: It's my pleasure, @HoneyThakuria